# Prove limits inequality

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

$(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}},(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are series of real numbers and they are both convergent. I need to prove that if $x_n\leq y_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $ \lim_{x->\infty}x_n \leq \lim_{x->\infty}y_n$

Comment: Show your work if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proceed by contradiction. Suppose that $\mu=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n>\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}y_n=\lambda$. Put $\varepsilon=\frac{\mu-\lambda}{2}$. Then there exists an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-\mu|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. Thus $x_n\in (\mu-\varepsilon,\mu+\varepsilon)=(\frac{\mu+\lambda}{2},\frac{3\mu-\lambda}{2})$ for all $n\geq N$. Hence $x_n>\frac{\mu+\lambda}{2}$ for all $n\geq N$. But $y_n\rightarrow \lambda$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Hence we can find a $y_m$ such that $y_m$ is closer to $\lambda$ then $x_n$. Can you finish this part yourself?

Edit: Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}y_n=\lambda$, there exists an $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|y_n-\lambda|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq M$. Thus $y_n\in (\frac{3\lambda-\mu}{2},\frac{\mu+\lambda}{2})$ for all $n\geq M$. Hence $y_n<\frac{\mu+\lambda}{2}$ for all $n\geq M$. Hence for all $n\geq \max\left\{N,M\right\}$ we have $y_n<\frac{\mu+\lambda}{2}<x_n$ contradicting our assumption.

Comment: $$|y_m-\lambda|< |x_n-\lambda| \Rightarrow -x_n+\lambda <y_m-\lambda<x_n-\lambda \Rightarrow -x_n+2\lambda < y_m < x_n $$. And from here is the contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: No, that's not correct. The first implication is wrong. Also it doesn't make much sense to look at that first inequality.

Comment: $x_n > \lambda$ and $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n = \lambda \Rightarrow lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}y_n < x_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ . And here is the contradiction

Comment: No, you are saying that $\lambda<x_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, but this might not be true. However, you should show that there exists a $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y_n>x_n$ to obtain the contradiction. You're getting closer, but you need to make precise arguments.

Comment: I don't get it. It's so annoying.

Comment: I updated the answer, should be clear now.